# `nicematrix` tabularnotes, is there a way to list them one after the other horizontally?

Tags: footnotes, nicematrix

I want to reduce space for a table in a report I am writing where I desire table footnotes using `nicematrix`. I am aware that using the package `enumitem` with the `inline` class option makes them so but this is global. I would like it to just be local, using the `nicematrix` package environment `NiceTabularX`, how can this be done please?

I am familiar with other methods but I am not sure how they relate to `nicematrix`. I couldn't see a way in the documentation, apologies if this is a duplicate, I could not see anything that related to `nicematrix`'s `\tabularnote` specifically.

How it looks:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{cX}
\toprule
\textbf{Year} & \textbf{Important milestones or key achievements\tabularnote{Caption note} in enzyme design}\\ \midrule
1997 & First fully automated design and experimental\tabularnote{This is even more text for an example} \\ \addlinespace[0.1em]
2003 & First globular protein designed with a fold\tabularnote{Text here} not observed in nature\\ \addlinespace[0.1em]
2007-08 & Text here\tabularnote{Tabular note text}.\\ \addlinespace[0.1em]
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabularX}
\end{document}
```

Ideally, I would like for the footnotes to be one after the other seperated with a `;` or a `\hspace`/punctuation of my choice if possible please.

Comment: Hi @JamesT If I understand you correctly, you want the table notes to appear below the table in an inline enumerate fashion? So to speak: using the `\tabularnote` as the label and text of an `\enumerate* \item`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    notes = 
     {
       para , 
       enumitem-keys-para = { itemjoin = \;;\; }
     }
  }

\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{cX}
\toprule
\textbf{Year} & \textbf{Important milestones or key achievements\tabularnote{Caption note} in enzyme design}\\ \midrule
1997 & First fully automated design and experimental\tabularnote{This is even more text for an example} \\ \addlinespace[0.1em]
2003 & First globular protein designed with a fold\tabularnote{Text here} not observed in nature\\ \addlinespace[0.1em]
2007-08 & Text here\tabularnote{Tabular note text}.\\ \addlinespace[0.1em]
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabularX}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: +1 I will add a comment for others as I normally wait quite a few hours to tick an answer but as you are the author of `nicematrix` (thanks!), I accepted pretty fast as you are the authority on this package, thank you!

Comment: Thanks @F.Pantigny . The manual explains the keys in section 13.4, but I wasn't sure on its use despite the example on page 38. Seeing it in action in your answer clarifies my confusion.